# Pyinstaller can't create the .exe file

Tags: python, numpy, cmd, anaconda, pyinstaller

I wanted to convert my python code into an executable and came across Pyinstaller package. However while running `pyinstaller --onefile my_python_code.py` from my cmd prompt it throws an ImportErrorWhenRunningHook for with numpy. I don't know where/ how to find the required module in my machine as per the error instructions. Can anybody please help me understand the error message and overcome the challenge?

**edit:**

> ... 281436 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py'
> from
> 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:138:
> UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R)
> MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under
> condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is
> not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see
> http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service   from . import
> *distributor_init Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import multiarray   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
> line 12, in 
> from . import overrides   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
> line 7, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py",
> line 107, in 
> from . import cbook, rcsetup   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook_*init*_.py",
> line 28, in 
> import numpy as np   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py",
> line 140, in 
> from . import core   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 48, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found.
>
> 281586 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from
> 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:138:
> UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R)
> MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under
> condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is
> not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see
> http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service   from . import
> *distributor_init Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import multiarray   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
> line 12, in 
> from . import overrides   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
> line 7, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py",
> line 107, in 
> from . import cbook, rcsetup   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook_*init*_.py",
> line 28, in 
> import numpy as np   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py",
> line 140, in 
> from . import core   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 48, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found.
>
> 281757 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from
> 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> 281769 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from
> 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:138:
> UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R)
> MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under
> condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is
> not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see
> http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service   from . import
> *distributor_init c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init**.py:138:
> UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R)
> MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under
> condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is
> not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see
> http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service   from . import
> *distributor_init Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import multiarray   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
> line 12, in 
> from . import overrides   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
> line 7, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>    File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py",
> line 140, in 
> from . import core   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 48, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import multiarray   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
> line 12, in 
> from . import overrides   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
> line 7, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in
> find_loader
> spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\importlib\util.py", line
> 94, in find_spec
> parent = **import**(parent_name, fromlist=['**path**'])   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py",
> line 140, in 
> from . import core   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 48, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found.
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks_*init*_.py",
> line 289, in get_module_file_attribute
> loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\pkgutil.py", line 499, in
> find_loader
> raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex ImportError: Error while finding loader for 'numpy.core' (<class
> 'ImportError'>:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found. )
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 409, in _load_hook_module
> self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py",
> line 593, in importlib_load_source
> return mod_loader.load_module()   File "", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
> File "", line 907, in
> load_module   File "", line 732,
> in load_module   File "", line 265, in
> _load_module_shim   File "", line 696, in _load   File "", line 677, in *load_unlocked   File "", line 728, in exec_module   File "", line 219,
> in *call_with_frames_removed   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py",
> line 29, in 
> pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks_*init**.py",
> line 506, in get_package_paths
> file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks_*init**.py",
> line 308, in get_module_file_attribute
> raise ImportError('Unable to load module attribute') from e ImportError: Unable to load module attribute
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
> *run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in
> *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py",
> line 7, in    File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py",
> line 114, in run
> run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py",
> line 65, in run_build
> PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 720, in main
> build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   File
> "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 667, in build
> exec(code, spec_namespace)   File "C:\Users\pandas10\Desktop\sa_fmcg_forecast\py_exe\fmcg_forecast.spec",
> line 17, in 
> noarchive=False)   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 242, in **init**
> self.**postinit**()   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
> line 160, in **postinit**
> self.assemble()   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 419, in assemble
> self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py",
> line 367, in process_post_graph_hooks
> module_hook.post_graph()   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 447, in post_graph
> self._load_hook_module()   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 413, in _load_hook_module
> self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename) PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import
> module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_numpy_core required by hook for module
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py.
> Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_numpy_core actually
> exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py:
> You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a
> pull-request to improve PyInstaller.

Note: I am using Anaconda and working in a separate environment than python *base or default*.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the whole log file, it seems like the installer did not download all the packages. I strongly recommend uninstalling the package and reinstalling it.

For uninstalling -
Open a command or terminal window (depending on the operating system)
cd into the project directory.
pip uninstall pyinstaller

And to reinstall -
If u r using PyCharm, just go to terminal on the bottom and type -
pip install pyinstaller

If u r using other things (I don't know about what you may be using) -
On Windows - press Windows Key + R and type cmd

On Mac - go to Finder/ Applications/ Terminal (I may be wrong)

Now type the command -
pip install pyinstaller

See the installation process and the packages being installed, if there is already a package installed, it will skip its installation, and if one isn't installed, pip will install it.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I uninstalled and reinstalled the package but didn't help still throws the same error. I have edited my question by adding detailed run log.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, obviously you are using the Anaconda python distribution. the Import error is happening cause the mkl-service's DLL can't be found, which should be located in:

**C:\Users\\anaconda3\Library\bin**

or

**C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\envs\<env_name>\Library\bin**

The most likely reason why the necessary DLLs can't be found (assuming mkl-service has been installed correctly) is the absence of the above directory in the PATH environment variable.

The mentioned path is usually prepended to the PATH by the Anaconda Prompt before build, so one solution is to run the command in the Anaconda Prompt.

Other solutions include:

1. Either append the mentioned directory to the PATH globally (by editing the PATH variable in the Windows Settings), or
2. Find a way to temporarily append it to the PATH (for the duration of your code's execution), specific to your development environment.